# Definite article before countable and uncountable nouns

Tags: definite-article, uncountable-nouns

Sorry if the concepts relating the definite article are such volatile!
Which articles (definite, indefinite, zero) can and can't be used before uncountable nouns?

For example:

- **The data** extracted from a node (correct, right?)
- A data extracted from .... (incorrect)
- **The tea** was delicious (right?)
- A tea produced by Ahmad company (incorrect)?

I thought wherever we can use "the" we also can use "a", but it seems we can use "the" before uncountable nouns but not "a" right? For example, I feel "the tea" could be incorrect! if yes why "the data" is not?

Comment: You ask a lot of question on ELL. May I suggest that you buy a good up-to-date scholarly grammar book, or go on a course?

Comment: @BillJ Maybe I should do that; however, as you see my English is not that bad ;) ! I also searched for this topic on the web but found no matching item, at least on Ell! I feel that I almost got the definite article topic, but the question above is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: @BillJ Also my questions history shows that I got many up-votes for my questions! then they could be concerns of many others too!

Comment: Yes, but if you are seriously interested in learning English grammar, you **must** read grammar textbooks. We can't teach you everything about grammar on this site. And please remember that we are volunteers; we don't get paid for helping you, so a "thank you" would be nice every now and then.

Comment: @BillJ I am thankful from you and others who helped me!, but I don't view this website the way you may see! I, as one who asks, and you, as one who answers, corporate to make a valuable resource for the future readers! I try to follow the rules, by not asking repeated questions, searching for my questions, explaining my concerns and .... this website needs both of us. There is also mechanisms to close a question!

Comment: @BillJ I also thanked you for your latest guide on chat room, but since there were a problem in the chat room, because I was on mobile, you may didn't see that :), anyway thank you and NOT BE TIRED (a literal translation of a Persian compliment)

Comment: Just a small note to one part -- we don't say "a data" because "data" is a plural noun. The singular is "datum".

Comment: @Roger Do we say "The tea"?

Comment: @Ahmad Yes, tea is still singular, so "the" or "a" can be used depending on the proper context. Both of your sentences about "tea" are correct usage.

Comment: The simple answer is yes. In fact the definite article "the" is compatible with all types of common noun: count singular, count plural, and non-count, e.g.  _Bring me [the ladder/ladders/the cement_ ]!

Comment: @BillJ I summarized some rules in my answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

When you use 'the' before a noun, you are referring to a specific instance of that noun. It is a *definite* article.

'A', an *indefinite* article refers to a abstract or general version of that noun, basically, it's up to the listener/reader/circumstances to fill in which specific instance (if any) fits that noun.

In your examples:

- *The data extracted from a node*, yes, correct. The specific data extracted from some node
- *A data extracted from ....* Incorrect. 'data' is plural, as Roger pointed out in the comments. If you had said *A datum extracted from...* you would be referring to any one datum extracted. Which datum would depend on context.
- *The tea was delicious* Correct. A specific tea was delicious
- *A tea produced by Ahmad company*. Is correct. In this case, you are referring to any one type of tea produced by Ahmad Company. The context would explain more information. For example, if you had: "ABC, a tea produced by Ahmad Company....", you would know which one. On the other hand, "Oh, I'm just drinking a tea produced by Ahmad Company....", would not define which tea.

So in answer to your question, **both 'a/an' and 'the' can be used before uncountable nouns**, but it is up to the rest of the sentence to determine if that usage is correct or not.

I did a quick search, and [this website](http://www.englishpage.com/articles/a-an-vs-the.htm) seems like a good resource for indefinite/definite articles.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the website! I also posted an answer to the question, please check if I am right there or not?

Comment: *There's **a man** at the door* refers to a specific man. You are mixing up definiteness and specificity. These are two different  characteristics. The *definite* and *indefinite* articles refer to definiteness, not specificity. Otherwise they'd be called the *specific* and  *unspecific* articles. *I married **a woman** from Alaska* refers to a specific, but indefinite woman.

Comment: @Clare, right. you didn't clarify *which* man or woman. Just *a* man or woman. It's up to the context to specify which one it is. In your case, 'man at the door' fills your condition of 'a man'. When you say 'a man' you could be talking about any person that falls under the category of 'man', the rest of your words explain the specifics.

Answer (score -3):

I tried to summarize some general rules.

- "the" can come before most nouns with some exception like most Proper nouns like Jane, London, however nouns like the Netherlands, the United States and some other nouns take "the".
- Some *uncountable* nouns can be *countable* in some context, so they can take "a/an". they are specified with [countable, uncountable] in some dictionaries like [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/tea) ([tea](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/tea), a tea, two teas, food, a food, foods)!
- Solely *uncountable* nouns like *information* can take "the" or "no article" (e.g. the [information](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/information) or information). But they can't get "a/an" (*an information* is incorrect), they are listed as [uncountable] in some dictionaries.
- Another important point is that a singular countable can't take "no article" (*a [computer](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/computer)*, *the computer*, *computers* but not *computer*).

Please note that the topic is about the definite and indefinite articles. Other determines like "my","some ",.... can replace a definite or indefinite article, which are out of question here.

Comment: If there is something wrong with my answer! please let me know!

Comment: I disagree. Many uncountable nouns can have no article, an indefinite article or a definite article.

Comment: @SovereignSun I also said the same! please read the answer carefully, those *uncountable* nouns that you mean can have an indefinite article are categorized as *countable/uncountable* nouns, it's actually dictionaries like "Longman" treat them.http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/tea, but pure uncountable nouns can't get an indefinite article.

Comment: Also note that some nouns can't get 'the' when it's already a part of that noun, like names.

Comment: @SovereignSun I also added Proper nouns exception

Comment: Don't you think, if there were some mathematical equation, scholars and linguists would have caught onto it by now? I really don't see this huge problem of articles, language is not about knowing when or where to place articles, it is much more sophisticated than that. (Note, not once did I use any article!)

Comment: @mari my table is either correct or not. If it has a problem then I expect others to say that. Otherwise, just casting a down vote or questioning my answer doesn't tell anything. Also,  my table doesn't simplify anything. One still should know which nouns are countable, which are uncountable and which both. And linguistics did that. You can find such categorization for entries of Longman dictionary.

Comment: You're very wrong about "computer", I can preface *computer* with "that" and ask: *How much is that computer?* (Did I use any articles in the comment?) Users will think looking at the table that articles are obligatory. The table says nothing about **when** or **how**

Comment: Nouns are  (often) prefaced by what is called  a **determiner**. A determiner includes *a/n*, *the*, *my*, *your*, *that*, *what*  etc. "**What** computer were you talking about?", "Have you seen **my** new computer?", "**Whose** computer is that?". In your answer you stated `a singular countable noun must take either "the" or "a/an",` You oversimplified.

Comment: @mari OK, that's not a big issue. I can modify it, what else?

Comment: @mari maybe some points I listed are obvious for you but to me they are important. For example many times I used to forget an article before singular countable nouns, but now I can review my texts to check where I need and where I don't need them. I don't say they have no exception but they can do guide an elementary or an intermediate learner.

Comment: I suppose you would like me to rewrite your answer :) But I repeat my earlier criticism, the table says nothing about "how" or "when" to use the articles. You would do well to look at this [recent ELL question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/116418/why-is-the-definite-article-used-in-i-live-in-the-city) and its answers.

Comment: @mari I replied your comment in my previous comment. They only guide the user to be cautious about using them barely or with incorrect articles. If I mistake please tell me can I ever say "an information"? Or to use "computer" with no specifier or determiner? If you admit, then the table says the same.

Comment: For the last time, the table says nothing about how or when to use articles, it is therefore inadequate, and incomplete. I know there are languages that do not have articles, and I appreciate that they seem daunting, so there's nothing to stop you from making up rules that make sense to you, if they help—great! But posting that table as an "answer" is not a good idea, it would have been better if you had posted it in a question and asked  if users could identify its flaws. And finally, if you have to explain a table , then you've defeated the purpose of creating a table in the first place. OK?

Comment: @Mari-LouA you again didn't answer my questions about *information* and *computer*, it seems my usage of "either" or "must" was a problem, and I resolved it now in my answer, the table isn't important but some of its points!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Also,  there is "definite" and  "indefinite" concepts in Persian too, we just don't complicate things, we have an "indefinite" article, and when it is absent then the noun is "definite" or "generic", the context would determine that. However, it could be a good feature of English to explicitly shows the "definite" nouns! but there are other simple tricks in absent of it, like you may don't need two crossing articles!

Comment: @Mari-LouA For example!, In Persian "give me a pen" means give me any pen, "give me pen" or "give me that pen" means "give me the pen". And "Pen is a device for writing" is a usage of "generic" noun. by the way we have an "object" determiner, **ra** which is usually comes after specific nouns (with object role) and help to make them determine, For example "Give me Pen ra" or "I read Book ra" (I read the book) vs. "I read book" (I read books).

Comment: @Mari-LouA ... So sometimes it interfere with Persian and I may say "Computer is a device for computing", however now I have learned to say either "a computer, the computer or computers"...and a single "computer" needs revising..

Comment: @Ahmad we can still say: "Many things became possible after the advent of computer". (I am not a native English speaker though)